# http://<Server Name>/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx unable to load the web service in browser

Tags: reporting-services

http:///ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx unable to load the web service in browser

I get HTTP 500 error on the Browser.

In ULS logs i get the below mentioned error:

Token Cache: Could not find SPSite for 'http://Server Name/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx'. Stack: '
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache.GetSubscriptionIdFromContext(String context)'.

Unexpected error in ProcessRequest: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.
 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Common.RSProxyUtils.get_ReportServerUrlString()
 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Soap.RSBaseHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)